# where to define timeline for gsap in vue/nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, gsap, nuxt.js

I have a list of buttons I would like to use `@click="play"` to trigger different functions to control the timeline.

Here is my current code:

The problem is I have my functions being called in data () and they are unable to reference the timeline created in `mounted:`

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <QuestionCard />
    <ul class="buttons">
      <button @click="playTimline()" id="btnPlay">play</button>
      <button id="btnPause">pause</button>
      <button id="btnResume">resume</button>
      <button id="btnReverse">reverse</button>
      <button id="btnSpeedUp">speed Up</button>
      <button id="btnSlowDown">slow down</button>
      <button id="btnSeek">seek 1 sec</button>
      <button id="btnProgress">go to 50%</button>
      <button id="btnRestart">restart</button>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<style lang="stylus">
.container 
  display flex
  justify-content center 
  align-items center
  height 100vh
  flex-direction column 

  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale

</style>


<script>
import QuestionCard from '../components/Layout/QuestionCard/index.vue'
import { TweenMax } from 'gsap'

export default {
  mounted: function () {
    const tl = new TimelineLite()
    const logo = document.getElementsByClassName('header')
    const question = document.getElementsByClassName('question-title')
    const description = document.getElementsByClassName('question-subtitle')
    const button = document.getElementsByClassName('answer-button')
    tl
      .from(logo, 0.3, {
        y: -15,
        autoAlpha: 0,
        ease: Back.easeOut
      },
      '-=0.10')
      .from(question, 0.3, {
        y: -15,
        autoAlpha: 0,
        ease: Back.easeOut
      },
      '-=0.10')
      .from(description, 0.3, {
        y: -15,
        autoAlpha: 0,
        ease: Back.easeOut
      },
      '-=0.10')
      .from(button, 0.3, {
        y: -15,
        autoAlpha: 0,
        ease: Back.easeOut
      },
      '-=0.10')
    tl.pause()
    // TweenMax.from(hello, 1, {
    //   y: 200
    // })
  },
  data () {
    return {
      tl: new TimelineLite(),
      playTimline: function () {
        console.log('hello world')
        this.tl.play()
      }
    }
  },
  components: {
    QuestionCard
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but here's my answer.

If you define it in data(), you can simply refer to it in mounted, as it will be available.
A couple of other issues here:

- the `playTimline` function on `data()` should actually be written inside the `methods` property.
- you should not get DOM references using `document.getElementsByClassName`, due to SSR and the way Nuxt/Vue render engine works. You should use the 'ref' attribute on the element, and access it via `this.$refs.[attributename]`.

(code with version 3 of GSAP)

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <QuestionCard />

    <!--
      I'm assuming inside the QuestionCard component you would have
      the various elements 'Logo', 'question', etc.
      They should be setup like:
      <img class="logo" **ref="logo"** img="[path]" >
      so later they can be accessed through the $refs object
    -->

    <ul class="buttons">
      <button @click="playTimline()" id="btnPlay">play</button>
      <button id="btnPause">pause</button>
      <button id="btnResume">resume</button>
      <button id="btnReverse">reverse</button>
      <button id="btnSpeedUp">speed Up</button>
      <button id="btnSlowDown">slow down</button>
      <button id="btnSeek">seek 1 sec</button>
      <button id="btnProgress">go to 50%</button>
      <button id="btnRestart">restart</button>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
import {gsap} from 'gsap/all'
import QuestionCard from '../components/Layout/QuestionCard/index.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    QuestionCard
  },

  data() {
    return {
      tl: gsap.timeline() // in GSAP v3, there's only one timeline type
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    this.tl
      .from(
        this.$refs.logo,
        0.3,
        {
          y: -15,
          autoAlpha: 0,
          ease: Back.easeOut
        },
        '-=0.10')
      .from(
        this.$refs.question, 
        0.3, 
        {
          y: -15,
          autoAlpha: 0,
          ease: Back.easeOut
        },
        '-=0.10')
        .from(
          this.$refs.description, 
          0.3, 
        {
          y: -15,
          autoAlpha: 0,
          ease: Back.easeOut
        },
        '-=0.10')
      .from(
        this.$refs.button, 
        0.3, {
          y: -15,
          autoAlpha: 0,
          ease: Back.easeOut
        },
        '-=0.10')

    this.tl.pause()
  },
}
</script>


<style lang="stylus">
    ...
</style>
```